# access play-Framework app from remote network (app running in dev mode)

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am running play-framework 2.5.3(**Java**) application locally on development mode.

I am able to access the application running on localhost from different computers on my local network

but when I am **trying to access it from remote network(internet),
I am getting this error**

```
This site can’t be reached

[SOMETHING_MY_IP] refused to connect.
```

I am using my public IP Address and port 9000 to access it .

Thanks

Comment: You may have to do some port forwarding first.

Comment: There are services like https://forwardhq.com or https://meetfinch.com that allows you to do what you want, but they are paid. If those are out of the question, you either will need to put your app online in a service like heroku or openshift, or configure your network/router to allow the connection. Good luck

Comment: thank u all.
I will try port Forwarding and other options.